# In Google Maps Draggable Directions how do you identify the location dragged to

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

With regard to...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

And the use of turning draggable on with...

```
var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true
};
```

And using the listener...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 
    'directions_changed', function() {}
```

I can only retrieve every nook and cranny of the route by using...

```
result = directionsDisplay.directions;
```

But what I want isn't within this object.

What I would like to know is where is the point located that I have just used to change the route. As I would like to store just that point not every point along the way.

Thanks for any help, as it's is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's at:

```
directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints;
```